# Redshift python connector columns names are byte string

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have the following table in redshift:

```
a | b
-----
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

If I want to extract it from Redshift to a `pd.DataFrame` I can do the following:

```
import redshift_connector
import pandas as pd

query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
conn = redshift_connector(user=user, host=host, password=password, port=port, database=database)

df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn)
```

I'm using the following package [redshift_connector](https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/). But the problem is that the name of the columns in `df` are byte-strings:

```
df['a']
```

This would return an error, since the name of the column is `b'a'`. Does anyone know any workaround for this? I already have written code using `psycopg2` which uses normal strings, and thus would like have a solution that doesn't change too much of the code.

Edit:

Versions

Python = 3.9.7

Redshift-connector = 2.0.889

Pandas = 1.2.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just fix this with one line

```py
df.columns = [col.decode("utf-8") for col in df.columns]
```

Or instead of using `pd.read_sql_query` use the connection approach suggested in the documentation

```py
cursor: redshift_connector.Cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")

result: pd.DataFrame = cursor.fetch_dataframe()
```

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in [v2.0.908](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-python-driver/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v20908-2022-06-30) of redshift-connector